# How to render a nested array?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting a response from an endpoint which is this:

```
[[{"1":"91"}],[{"1":"1"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}]]
```

I fetched them and I get the results but I cannot render them. This is what I have been trying:

```
render() {
        const {count} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {count.count && count.count.map(item => (
                    item.value.map(data => (
                        data.value.map(x => (
                            <p>{x.value}</p>
                        ))
                    ))
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I expect the out to be all the numbers shown in the json response. Ex. 91 1 0 0 0 etc.

Comment: please provide your sample `this.state.count`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. You're showing one object and handle it as it totally different. You're using 3 `map` while you have 2 levels in the object. Also, where `value` prop came from? In the object, there is not `value`. And you're expect the result to contains `94..` but you have no `94` in the object. Where the `count` come from? etc.

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting?

Comment: @DaniVijay No I am not getting any error.

Comment: @Ashish state = {
        count: {}
    };

Comment: Maybe you could try to reproduce the issue with tools like https://stackblitz.com/fork/react. This way it will much easier for us to help you..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6naael @MoshFeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the structure the array you're trying to iterate is like an array of arrays, with objects within. So, start iterate first and second arrays first, then iterate the object within. `Object.keys` can be used for that.

You can access it like the following,

```
...
    <div>
      {count &&
        count.length > 0 &&
        count.map(
          item =>
            item.length > 0 &&
            item.map(
              el =>
                Object.keys(el).length > 0 &&
                Object.keys(el).map(val => <p>{el[val]}</p>)
            )
        )}
    </div>
...
```

Codesandbox demo [**here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-beaver-9i6tx)

Stackblitz demo [**here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-55mj54)

Comment: Please share your state. It like, `count: {count: [[{"1":"91"}],[{"1":"1"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}],[{"1":"0"}]]}`, right?

Comment: `count:
Array[8]
0:
Array[1]
0:
{…}
1:
"91"`

Comment: Directly iterate `count` then, instead of `count.count`. I've edited the answer. Refer codesandbox too.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-55mj54

^ Added the array statically because the API is not available. Also added a check for `count` is empty or not.